# Passing DOM object to function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, dom, typescript-typings

I have an TypeScript app where I have function that selects html element, and another function that modifies that element. This far, I have done it like this:

```
const modifyElement(element:any):void => {
 // do stuff to element
}
// call the function
modifyElement(document.querySelector("#id"))
```

ButI don't like doing it with type any, so what is the type I should give to it? ( or is this whole concept of passing HTML elements invalid TypeScript)

Comment: The parameter type would be `Element | null`. But `querySelector` takes a generic type parameter, so if you know that the element with that ID is an `input` (for instance), you could use `HTMLInputElement | null`. TypeScript will infer `HTMLInputElement` as the type argument for `querySelector`.

Comment: Thanks! But that gives me the problem that the argument with type Element | null, TypeScript throws error 'Object is possibly null'

Comment: That's because it's true, `querySelector` can return `null`. You need a guard handling that. (Or a non-null type assertion, but type assertions are generally poor practice because they often end up being wrong.)